# Как положить значения из двумерного массива в обычный?

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, консоль, многомерные-списки

Мне нужно вывести в массив диагональ.

Например, есть двумерный массив:

```
int[][] arr = { { 0, 1, 2 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 1, 1, 1 } };
```

Из него должен получиться одномерный массив `[0,5,1]`.

Вот мой код:

```
public class MatrixDiagonal {
  public int[] getDiagonal(int[][] matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0, x = matrix[i].length - 1; j<matrix[i].length; j++, x--) {
          if (i == j) {
          //??? 
          }
        }
    return;
    }
  }
```

Comment: а почему должно получиться 0,5,1. в моем понимании, если запихнуть духмерный массив в одномерный, то должно получиться [0,1,2,4,5,6,1,1,1]

Comment: Задача состоит в том,чтобы метод вернул диагональ значений в одномерный массив взяв значения из двумерного.

Comment: Наша диагональ это 0,5,1 ,если идти вот так \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос, то вам нужно вывести все числа с диагонали.

И у вас есть двумерный массив:

```java
int [][] arr = new int [][]{ 
                             {0, 1, 2},
                             {4, 5, 6}, 
                             {1, 1, 1}                                   
                          };
```

**Как решить вашу проблему:**

1. Создайте переменную-счётчик (зачем она нужна, увидите дальше). Присвойте ей значение 0:

```java
int counter = 0;
```

2. Создайте новый одномерный массив, в который будут записываться уже готовые нужные значения. Длинна этого массива будет равна количеству массивов в двумерном массиве:

```java
int [] newArray = new int [arr.length];
```

3. Создайте цикл `foreach`, который будет проходиться по массивам, которые лежат внутри двумерного (двумерный массив - массив массивов). В цикле увеличивайте переменную `counter` на `1`. В индекс под номером `counter` массива `newArray` кладите индекс под номером `counter` массива `j`.

```
for(int[] j : arr){
     newArray[counter] = j[counter];
     counter++;
}
```

4. Можно вывести новый массив на экран, чтобы проверить, всё ли верно. Это можно сделать циклом, но так быстрее:

```java
System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

Вывод:

```
[0, 5, 1]
```

**P.S**
**Я убедительно вас прошу не просто скопировать решение, а разобраться в нём. Я специально всё очень подробно расписал.** Если мой ответ помог, то вы можете пометить его как решение =).

Comment: Зачем такое городить, когда достаточно одного сермяжного цикла for по matrix[i][i]?

Comment: @MBo 1) Есть несколько вариантов решения 2) "городить" - громко сказано, всего-то одну переменную создал. 3) Когда код проще выглядит даже глазу приятнее.

Comment: Мне понравилось решение ,хорошо знать несколько способов решения,спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Задача имеет смысл для *квадратного* входного массива/матрицы, поэтому считаем, что это условие выполняется.

1. Создаёте целочисленный массив для хранения элементов на диагонали, его размер такой же, как и количество строк во входной матрице.
2. В простом цикле заполняется массив-результат, для элементов на главной диагонали индекс строки равен индексу столбца.
3. Возвращается массив-результат.

Реализация с использованием цикла не приводится в педагогических целях.

С использованием Stream API реализация упрощается до следующей:

```java
public static int[] getDiagonal(int[][] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length) // индексы строк/колонок на главной д.
            .map(i -> arr[i][i])
            .toArray();
}
```

Comment: Я на том уровне где стримы не проходились, но все равно спасибо )

Comment: У вас написан код с циклами, значит вы знаете, как их использовать.  Поэтому готовое решение с одинарным циклом я не приводил, так как у вас оно должно получиться без посторонней помощи.  Алгоритм описан достаточно ясно на мой взгляд.